# How can I center two textviews in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have an imageView in the center of my Relative Layout, and I want to center two TextViews under the imageView. But it's not working.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want to center "Text 1" and "Text 2" under the image.

Here is the XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.googlemap.TestActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Title"/>

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:contentDescription="Desc"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"   
                android:textSize="25sp"        
                android:text="Text 1" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numOfPlayersTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
                android:text="Text 2"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Title"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/titleTextView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:contentDescription="Desc" 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="Text 1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/numOfPlayersTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 2"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add *android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"* (there is no image src in my code). I'll update it

Comment: just a question: If I want to add multiple textViews under "Text1" and "Text2", should I add Linear Layouts inside the Linear Layout you made ?

Comment: If there is one text in each line use LinearLayout with Vertical orientation otherwise i think you need to add a new LinearLayout for each line

Answer (score 1):

You can center them Horizontally below the image view this way .

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@imageViewId"
```